# Arrival of patients in a hospital

Tags: probability

> The department of emergency admission in a hospital has two beds for trauma patients. New patients that arrive will be send to another hospital if both beds are taken. Trauma patients arrive according to a Poisson process, with a average of $\lambda$ per day. Each day an average of 4.2 patients is accepted. In addition, 16% of the time both beds are taken. Calculate $\lambda$. What percentage of patients will be transferred to another hospital?

I do not really know how to start with this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Starting point**

$\lambda$ patients come in each day (at average, poisson distributed) but only 4.2 patients are accepted, where$4.2 < \lambda$, *because some of the time both beds are occupied*.

So $$\lambda (1 - 0.16) = 4.2$$

And then the averaqge number of patients transferred per day is $\lambda - 4.2$.

If your gut feeling tells you that 16% of the patients will be transferred out, without going through the calculations, then you are beginning to get a good feel for probabilities.

By the way, a much more subtle question would be "assuming the length of stay is also Poisson distributed, what is the average length of stay (to keep both beds occupied 16% of the time)?